# extractSingle not called when accessing the index?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the impression that `extractSingle` is only called when finding a specific document:

```
store.find('company', 'this-one');
```

But it is not called when doing a "find all":

```
store.find('company');
```

At least this is what I see in my traces (but there are errors, so it could be that ember is interrupted). Is this correct? I expected `extractSingle` to be called once for each element in the collection, but maybe it is not implemented like that.

What method do I need to implement in order to extract a collection?

### EDIT

Looking at the ember-data source, I see that there is a `extractArray` method. I assume I need to implement that. No idea why the default implementation does not call `extractSingle` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collections usually come back different than a single record, which is why `extractArray` exists, if your api is such that each single element needs `extractSingle` called on it, call it from `extractArray`.